# Add blur background in Windows Phone applications

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, blur

How can i add blur background with some transparency in my Windows Phone application.

I can create transparent background using opacity property or using first two alpha number of hexa color code #**AF**FFFFFF. But I am not able to find any way to add blur for any panel. Is there some way or work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blur effect is not supported out of the box on Silverlight.

It's possible with [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)

On loading your image into `WriteableBitmap wb`, you can get the blurred version with:

```
var wb2 = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur3x3);
```

Comment: Can I add a semi transparent blur background so that anything behind that panel looks blur? something like Aero effect.

Comment: @BalrajSingh That's not how blur works. Anything you want blurred you will have to render onto WriteableBitmap first.

Comment: I got a link http://charly-studio.com/blog/aero-effect-blurry-transparency-in-wpf/ but it tells how to apply in wpf so how can i change it for Windows Phone?

Comment: @BalrajSingh That's the thing - Effects were supported in wpf, aren't in silverlight. It was simple there, it's quite complicated to achieve in silverlight.